# Black Screen on Ubuntu Install + garbled installer

Tags: unity, system-installation, ati, graphics

My desktop is black and every window is garbled.

In have 2 AMD Radeon 7790s in crossfire And fx 8core CPU at 4.6ghz each. 16gb of ram.

The unity bar and dash icon are coloured with the default Background's colours but the desktop is entirely black and every window is garbled. I cannot install because of this.

This has happened with every version of Ubuntu I have tried to install. Does it not like crossfire or something, or is my hardware too new?

Comment: Have you tried Xubuntu? It does not use unity, and maybe it can work for you. Brand new Xubuntu 14.04 is more than ok, and frankly I think it does a great job though it may not look as fancy as Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Manjaro works fine, heck, even my own distro that I made works fine. Any ideas on how to get Ubuntu to work? I really like the UI, features, support and community.

I think the issue is that it doesn't have the graphics drivers on the USB for me to load from. When I use these I get no issues but I cannot install these on the USB (I think). Any ideas would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Any ideas guys?

Comment: Visit [this page](http://forums.amd.com/game/messageview.cfm?catid=488&threadid=167409), it says you should change some settings in the Catalyst software. Speaking of Catalyst, do you use the latest drivers for Linux from AMD support page or the drivers Ubuntu provided you via the repos?

Comment: This was the installer from the LiveCD. I fixed it by correctly adding nomodeset to it and installing my drivers after installing ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the issue I used nomodeset in the grub menu on the 'linux' line. This puts it in a worse graphics mode but only to install. I then installed my drivers when installed.